# How to verify receipt of packets at remote XBee Device

Tags: python-3.x, xbee, zigbee

I have a question pertaining to the use of the Xbee Python API library. I want to send a synchronous unicast packet from a local device to a remote device. My local device is a ZigBee module i have connected to a pc. The remote device consists of a zigbee module connected via usb to a raspberry pi. My question is how do I verify receipt of the data packet at the remote device? Based on my understanding from reading the documentation on the XBee library i have to install the API library on both the pc and raspberry pi, and create an application on the local device to send the packet to the remote device but after doing this is there anything that displays at either the remote device or local device that shows the packet was received successfully?

Thanks 
Tellrell

Comment: Update: Based on research, I believe I need an application on the receiver that will read the incoming data. I'll implement this on the raspberry pi and come back with an update.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the Python library works, but running the XBee in API mode and using a non-zero "frame id" field of the transmit frame results in a "transmit status" frame coming back if the frame was delivered to the remote XBee module.  I don't know how the Python library will expose that information to your code, though.